# dynamic function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

hello dynamic function does not work
Where is the problem?

DynamicCreateFunction function works but runtimeFunction not working.

http://i.hizliresim.com/VyXkRv.png

```
  function DynamicCreateFunction(func) {

    var runtimeFunction = new Function(func);
    runtimeFunction ();
}

     function ExpensesGrid()
    {
         alert('working');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a `function` as parameter, you can do it like this normally:

```
function DynamicCreateFunction(callback){
   callback.call(this); //or .apply() or simply callback()
}
```

if you want to execute `ExpensesGrid` do it like

```
DynamicCreateFunction(ExpensesGrid);
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0):

```
 hello thanks for the reply but I see the `"call" is not supported error` why ?

    function DynamicCreateFunction(callback){
   callback.call(this); //or .apply() or simply callback()
}
```

but problem solved, alternative solved, "function is working"

```
dynamicFunction = window[func]; 
dynamicFunction();
```

thank you –

Comment: Maybe you have somewhere. Anyway, this solution should do the trick, but it binds the function to the window every time. Maybe this is not necessary